# Split cell data in one row to different row and copy the other data in the same row across all newly added rows

Tags: python, pandas

[Here is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6sEv.png)

I need to have the PRODUCT column's data to separate into separate into different rows and at the same time keeping the same data from other columns as they are related, is it possible to achieve with Python Pandas

Comment: Add code, errors, and data as text, not screenshots because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and add text.

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

1. split product column
2. explode it

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Fabric Code":["TW1220P","FN1041 / FN10768","C01016","ST1028"],"Product":["6J052510","1J835610","1J907410,21906510,3J910510","1K211310,2K210910,3K211210"],"Pattern/Color":["Deep Navy BL31755","65048A 3-20NART-4782A-W","70160C GPW-F20-PA2090","57060A GPW-S21PA005A"]})
df["expandedprod"]=df.Product.str.split(",")
df.explode("expandedprod")
```

**output**

```
      Fabric Code                     Product            Pattern/Color expandedprod
          TW1220P                    6J052510        Deep Navy BL31755     6J052510
 FN1041 / FN10768                    1J835610  65048A 3-20NART-4782A-W     1J835610
           C01016  1J907410,21906510,3J910510    70160C GPW-F20-PA2090     1J907410
           C01016  1J907410,21906510,3J910510    70160C GPW-F20-PA2090     21906510
           C01016  1J907410,21906510,3J910510    70160C GPW-F20-PA2090     3J910510
           ST1028  1K211310,2K210910,3K211210     57060A GPW-S21PA005A     1K211310
           ST1028  1K211310,2K210910,3K211210     57060A GPW-S21PA005A     2K210910
           ST1028  1K211310,2K210910,3K211210     57060A GPW-S21PA005A     3K211210
```

Comment: Rob Raymond,  thank you very much.  Its a very big help for me.